# Sharepoint look up column - date format

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a date field, and it has the date in the format - 11/2/2011 11:40 AM

**How ever my requirement is to get the date in the format - *02 Nov 2011 11:40 AM***

For that I created a look up field for the said field and used the formula as - **=TEXT(Modified,"dd mmm yyyy hh:mm ")**

It resulted in the following date format - 02 Nov 2011 11:40 (It is a 24 hour format).

Now my question is how can I edit the formula to get the time in 12 hour format.

Thank you guys !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=TEXT(Modified,"dd mmm yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")
```